# Launching activity from a singleinstance activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, launchmode

I have 3 activities:

A, B , C

A has `singleInstance` launchMode.

A is the main activity, which launches B, B launches C,   then I press the home button and open the app again.

A is opened, but when A tries to launch B, the existing stack is opened instead (returns to existing C)

Is this the expected behaviour?

Comment: My first question is always "Why?" Why are you using launch mode `singleInstance`? In general this is not needed and usually creates more problems than it solves (your question being proof of this statement).

Comment: I am not using it, but I was testing different launchmodes to document different behaviors, it took my by surprise that singleInstance had this unintuitive behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If A is `singleInstance`, when A launches B, Android automatically adds `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_INSTANCE` to the `Intent` (because A is `singleInstance`) and because of that it creates a new task with B at the root of the task. Then B launches C. Andriod launches C into the same task as B (this is the normal behaviour). So now you have 2 tasks: One with just A in it, and another which has B at the root, with C on top of that.

Now you go back to the task containing A. When A launches B again, Android again adds `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` to the `Intent`). Then, because `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` is set, Android looks for an existing task that has B at the root. Since it finds one, it simple brings that task to the foreground in whatever state the task was in when that task went to the background. This is the normal and expected behaviour.

**NOTE:** This is just one more reason NOT to use the special launch modes `singleInstance` and `singleTask`, because they have lots of nasty, undocumented, misunderstood side-effects.

Comment: Thanks, but i dont understand why android adds NEW_TASK for "singleInstance" activity. SINGLE INSTANCE is just a single instance, right?

Comment: @M.UsmanKhan If you declare an `Activity` as "single instance", this means that no other activities will be launched into the same task as the "single instance" `Activity`. So if the "single instance" `Activity` launches another `Activity`, Android automatically adds the flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` to ensure that the target `Activity` is launched into another task. Is that clear now?